# How to truncate complex html by lines

Tags: javascript, truncation

I am trying to truncate complex html by lines in order to be able to display a show more link after a certain number of lines has been reached. I found a great library trunk8.js which truncates by lines..but if falls short when it comes to truncating complex html. So for my particular case I  overrode the truncate function so that I can handle complex the using another truncation function which gracefully leaves complex html tags intact. Truncation will work great with html but I am stuck on how to accurately calculate where to put show more more based on the number of lines

[image]

As seen  in the image above I am trying to truncate to 7 lines but if the user input contains white spaces shown in yellow my calculations will be wrong because I am not accounting for the white spaces. My initial line of thought was that if I can calculate the length of the spaces in yellow for each line and convert it to characters, I can add this offset to the maximum number number of characters, then I can know where to put approximately the show more link. Is this the best approach to this problem and if not ,any suggestions to make my life easier.

This is a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/xvpbYvlh0TK3nQRJ6sEN/) of what I have tried so far and I am stuck in my truncateHTML() function in the trunk8.js where I am only now truncating based on the maximum length of the string.

Comment: Is there any reason you just don't set the size of the div and have overflow:hidden, and then have the "show more" just absolutely positioned in the bottom right?.  You can also detect if the div overflows, so you can hide/show the "show more"

Comment: Thanks for your input. Initially we had it like that , but the product team requested that the show more link must be dynamic and be adjacent to the text depending on the length of the text or  a specific number of lines. So we were having issues correctly positioning the show more correctly for different user inputs

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!! After a couple of google searches and heavy debugging sprints, I stumbled upon a library [truncate.js](https://github.com/jeffchan/truncate.js?files=1) which I customized the truncatedNestednode() function for my needs.

```
 element.appendChild(child);
        /** Customized--here **/
        var clonedNode = {};
        if ($clipNode.length) {
            if ($.inArray(element.tagName.toLowerCase(), BLOCK_TAGS) >= 0) {
                // Certain elements like <li> should not be appended to.
                $element.after($clipNode);
            }
            else
            {    //Removed the commented line to put showmore next to the last line of text
                 $element.prev().append($clipNode);
                //$element.append($clipNode);

                }
        }
```

In case someone faced this problem in the past, I have posted my revised plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/30OPJueBgmw2fWKQurdp)